# Prove $\bar{A}\setminus \bar{B} \subset \overline{A\setminus B }$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Here is my approach so far

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of the metric space $(M,d)$

My thoughts on how to prove it, is to choose an element $x$ from $\bar{A}\setminus \bar{B}$ and show it exists in ,$\overline{A\setminus B }$

Choose $x\in \bar{A}\setminus \bar{B} \rightarrow x\in \bar{A} \wedge x\notin \bar{B} \rightarrow \forall r>0 : C(x,r)\cap A \neqØ \wedge \exists r'>0:C(x,r') \cap B =Ø$

... Here $C(x,a)$ is the circle with radius $a$ with center $x$

But now I'm not sure how to continue?

Comment: $\bar A\backslash \bar B=\bar A\iff \bar A\cap \bar B=\emptyset$ !

Comment: Made a typo - I wanted to show that $\bar{A}\setminus \bar{B} \subset \overline{A\setminus B }$. A and B har subset of the metric space $(M,d)$. My thoughts on how to prove it, is to choose an element $x$ from $\bar{A}\setminus \bar{B}$ and show it exists in ,$\overline{A\setminus B }$, but I'm not sure on how to continue

Comment: I'm not sure what $\bar{A}$ is callled, but it's the union of the boundary and interior of A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Pick any $r > 0$. We also have $r' > 0$ such that $C(x,r') \cap B = \emptyset$. So for $r'' = \min(r,r') > 0$ we have that $C(x,r'') \cap A \neq \emptyset$, and any point in this intersection cannot be in $B$, by the property of $r'$. And this point is certainly in $C(x,r)$ as well, so this ball intersects $A \setminus B$.

Hence $x \in \overline{A \setminus B}$, as required.